# Toolbar extremely big after updating to 2.93

Tags: interface

I just updated my blender from 2.79 to 2.93 and the toolbar is extremely big. I can't seem to figure out how to decrease the width again to what it is normally.
For now I have collapsed it completely and I am accessing the tools via the spacebar atm.
[image]

Comment: Grab its right edge and drag to make smaller. Then save startup file.

Comment: It doesn't want to be grabbed. That's the first thing I tried :(
I might as well re-install it from scratch. That's easier anyway with all the addons

Comment: Mouse around the right edge do you see  the two way arrow cursor?

Comment: Nope. It does work on my home machine when I checked it via teamviewer. It doesn't work on my work pc though

Comment: It is okay. At least I know I wasn't going crazy and I'll just install it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @batFINGER said: Grab its right edge and drag to make smaller. Then save startup file. It is rather hard to find because the window edge is actually invisible, point your mouse just to the right of visible area. Aim for about half way between the "Select Box" entry and the onscreen display. Look for the double arrows <-> as shown.

[image: The t menu wide]
[image: the t menu narrow]

Comment: and as answered it doesn't work anymore. It is the first thing I tried. I can do it just fine on my other computer but this one doesn't allow me to do it. I've re-installed it from scratch and after re-installing it works again. It might have been caused by one of the addons or some weird bug.